# Adding control template to project

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use metro styled combobox item in windows phone 7 (mango). I ve found toturial to do this http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/metro-style-combobox-windows but i don't know where should i put code of control template (it should work on every combobox on project).

Any ideas?
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you want to use that `ComboBox`? The link you've posted is a hack to get it to work on Windows Phone. Have you taken a look at the `ListPicker` control from the [Silverlight toolkit](https://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550)?

This [article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx) provides a great introduction on how to use it.

Comment: I think we should let [Dennis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/303696/dennis-delimarsky) answer why. He apparently love to advocate the bad UX controls ;-)